# Convert a Char Array to a String

Tags: javascript

How do you convert an array of characters to a string in JavaScript?

```
var s = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];
// How to convert s to a string?
```

Comment: To see this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/sikusikucom/XMjZH/

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Use [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
string = s.join("");
```

Comment: @Digital_Pane: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for i.e. the string will be "Hello".

Answer (score 8):

You do it this way:

```
var str = s.join();
```

Comment: Without an argument, `.join()` will use `","` as a default. But then OP didn't specify how it should be converted, so nothing wrong with your answer.

Comment: With `.join()` i.e. without an argument, the string will be "H,e,l,l,o". Yes, as @patrick mentioned, since I didn't specifically stated what output I was looking for (actually, "Hello") this answer is still valid.

Answer (score 8):

The join command lets you set the token among the items in the array.

Ex1:

```js
function print(str) {
  $("#result").append("<p>" + str + "</p>");  
}

print(["A", "B", "C"].join()); // "A,B,C"
print(["A", "B", "C"].join("-")); // "A-B-C"
print(["A", "B", "C"].join("||")); // "A||B||C"
print(["A", "B", "C"].join("")); // "ABC"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Or use String.

```
var string = String([1,2,3]);
```

Comment: That's the same as `s.toString()` or any implicit conversion to string - unlikely to be what the OP asked for.

Comment: That would yield `1,2,3`, but the OP almost certainly wants `123`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array like `let array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']` you can try `array1.join('')` the ourput will be `'abc'`