# How to convert an object to a string JS

Tags: javascript

I have the following object called result of the form

```
0: "X"
1: "S"
2: "Z"
3: "C"
4: "W"
5: "X"
6: "M"
7: "A"
8: "D"
9: "V"
10: "M"
11: "F"
12: "I"
13: "H"
```

. How could I convert this object into a string of characters of the form XSZCWXMADVFIH ? I tried JSON.stringify (), but these functions return a response of the form

```
["X","S","Z","C","W","X","M","A","D","V","M","F","I","H"]
```

Comment: Use `array.join('')` to turn your array of items into a string without characters in between.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values + `join`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a Char Array to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425374/convert-a-char-array-to-a-string)

Comment: If `JSON.stringify()` returns `[...]`, then the object you are referring to is an array.

Comment: Is it an object, or is that just the output of you logging an array in the console?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.values` to extract the object values into an array and then use the `Array.prototype.join()` method to join them by `''`

```js
const obj ={
0: "X",
1: "S",
2: "Z",
3: "C",
4: "W",
5: "X",
6: "M",
7: "A",
8: "D",
9: "V",
10: "M",
11: "F",
12: "I",
13: "H",
};

const str = Object.values(obj).join('');

console.log(str)
```

Comment: You're assuming it's an object from what the OP said but that data could also the output of an array logged in the console..

Comment: Also if you were to add `15: "J"` this would add `"J"` to the 14th index and not the 15th index. (which might not matter for OPs output). This also might not work in environments that use engines that implement versions of the spec earlier than ES2020, as object property order for `Object.values()` wasn't specified back then (while most browser would iterate the keys in numeric order, it isn't guaranteed if they're pre ES2020). But all of this might not matter if OPs object is actually an array :)